# Recuperar commits después de forzar un push

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

Bien, estaba trabajando en la pc de costumbre y tenía todo lo local conectado a lo remoto, venía haciendo push lo mas bien con todo el material del cuatrimestre por clases.
Ahora, en otra pc hice solo lo de una clase del día y quise pushear (conectada al mismo repositorio en Github) cuando claramente no tenía lo del remoto en esa pc y no lo quise traer (solo quería pushear lo de esa clase y omitir lo demas) no pude, me cansé y opté por forzar el push.. se hizo pero me dejó tanto el local (que solo tenia lo de esa clase) y el remoto actualizados en ese mismo commit.. la pregunta es, como puedo acceder a lo que estaba antes de este ultimo push forzado, se puede? cómo? Busqué info en internet, metí en consola el comando git reflog pero no me aparecen los anteriores commits ni con git log-g
Hay alguna forma de recuperarlos para no tener que hacer otro repositorio o commitear de nuevo?
Pd: ya sé para la próxima que crear una nueva rama me pude evitar todo esto, pero ahora ya me la mandé.

Comment: No se puede, la única forma es buscar en una computadora que no haya hecho pull a tus cambios y hacer el push force de nuevo. y se quedará justamenteen la última versión que hizo pull, no en la versión que estaba antes de lo tuyo.

Comment: Primero, super agradecida por la respuesta.. ya leer otra opinión o experiencia siempre suma. Segundo, seguí investigando y los pude 'recuperar', dejo abajo la solución que encontré por si a alguien mas le sirve.

Comment: Desde local en la pc que tenía todo lo del cuatrimestre solté en consola (antes de añadir y commitear cambios) el comando: git pull --allow-unrelated-histories, que lo que hace es permitir que historias o ramas que no estén fusionadas puedan hacerlo, Tuve que hacer es el pull hacia el remoto y después solucionar el conflicto en un merge (con esta clase puntual que tenía repetida) asi que seleccioné desde vsc los archivos que quería dejar y ualá, hice el nuevo commit y un push para terminar y tanto en el local como en el remoto todo está ok.. Solucionada la macana. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Igual podrías poner tu solución como respuesta en tu pregunta y aceptarla, de esta forma puedes ayudar a alguien que llegue tener el mismo problema que tú y esté buscando información.